# module.export function not returning results

Tags: node.js, module, return

I'm having some problems returning results from a module function.
Below are two files that I'm working with.

When I call the exported function it returns nothings.
Any suggestions/fixes as to why?  Does it have to do with callbacks?

**models/index.js**

```
module.exports = exports = function(library) {    
    modCodes.findOne({name: library}, {modcode:1}, function(err, mc) {
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
      var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + mc.modcode + '?safe=true');
      var models = {
        Books: db.model('books', require('./schemas/books'))
        }

        return models;
    });

};
```

**books.js**

```
var Models = require('../models');    
console.log(Models("myLibrary")); //return nothing
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason you're getting no results is that you're trying to return a function value synchronously from an asynchronous callback. Instead of providing a function value, the return statement will instead stop the function, as `return;` would normally do. This is why you must use a callback for asynchronous operations:

```
module.exports = exports = function(library, callback) {
  modCodes.findOne({name: library}, {modcode: 1}, function (err, mc) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + mc.modcode + '?safe=true');
    var models = {
      Books: db.model('books', require('./schemas/books'))
    }
    callback(models);
  });
};
```

And this is how you would be able to use it:

```
var Models = require('../models');    
Models('myLibrary', function(models) {
  console.log(models);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve similar  problem in different way. I am not sure whether it is right way.

in main node js I am using a model named product. I am passing product and res to misc.js. Following is part of my server.js file

```
var misc = require('./misc');
app.get('/groupbyCategory', function(req,res,next)
   {
     var res2; 
     misc.addX(product,res);
    })
```

IN misc.js doing group by function and will return that value to straight way to angular controller. it is **not necessary** to return the result to server.js and from server.js to return angular controller. So i feel waiting and other call back seems unnecessary.
Inside misc.js i keep following code.

```
exports.addX = function(product,res) {
 product.aggregate([

 { $group: {
 _id: {category: "$category"},
     count: { $sum: 1 }
        }}    
     ], function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
     console.log(err);
     return err; 
       }
       else
       {  
       //return result;

        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
        }
    });


};
```